# Python: How to Write str json to csv file?

Tags: python, json, string, csv

The string is inside JSONThe variable is NAME

My code:

```
 f = open(out_filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
 info = product["Name"]
 print("product_info: " + info + "\n")
 f.write(info + ", ")
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you do now? And what else you want to achieve?

Comment: have you tried considered using python pandas library for this task?  Seems like a perfect fit.

Comment: Use the `json` module to read JSON and the `csv` module to write CSV. They are both in the standard library and ready to use.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
import csv

out_filename = "output.txt"
info = "Amazon2"

with open(out_filename, mode='w') as test_file:
    employee_writer = csv.writer(test_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    employee_writer.writerow([info])
```

Comment: Why open the file and write twice?

Comment: It is writing once on my computer, how is it writing twice?

Comment: First you use `f.write` and then `employee_writer.writerow`.

Comment: ```f.write``` is from the original code, I just showed how to write csv in the end. I removed ```f.write``` now.

Answer (score -1):

import json
product["name"]="product_name"
json.dump(product)

f.write(product)